# How to tell if a call to system() has exited?

Tags: c

In C I wrote a code using `system()` to start another application , say abc.exe .Now how do I find if abc.exe has exited and when it has done so , I want to run another application, say xyz.exe .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system()` is synchronous i.e. when it is done you simply get to the next instruction of your code, so basically it should be :

```
 system("abc");
 system("xyz");
```

also `system` returns the exit status of executed program, so if there is a dependency between programs and `xyz` can't be executed without successful execution of `abc`, you should check  ret status of `abc`

```
 if(system("abc") != -1 )
    system("xyz");
```

Comment: The return value depends on the system and the application. In many systems, 0 is used to indicate that the command was successfully executed. But not in all.

Comment: if it returns any non zero value for an error or 0 for everything going good, instead of using > or < shouldn't I use != or ==

Comment: OK got that.,., tnx everyone , the application's running now without any problem,.,

Answer (score 1):

Call the application after the first `system(`). [System()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) is synchronous.

```
system("abc");
system("xyz");
```

Like anthropomorphic notice,

> synchronous means that a call to system("abc") will only return after
> "abc" is done.

You are able to verify the execution with the return value. Generally a non zero value is returned, if the program was not execute currently.

> In many systems, 0 is used to indicate that the command was
> successfully executed and other values to indicate some sort of error.
>
> If command is a null pointer, the function returns a non-zero value in
> case a command processor is available and a zero value if it is not.
> If command is not a null pointer, the value returned depends on the
> system and library implementations, but it is generally expected to be
> the status code returned by the called command, if supported.

Comment: Ok , so i just need to put the next call directly below it And to make it work better using if-else check if it executed successfully  ,., Got that ,.,.Thanks all of you

Comment: Yes, exactly. That should do it. You could also add a code snippet to your question.

Comment: To clarify, what he means by "synchronous" is that a call to `system("abc")` will only return after `"abc"` is done running. So if `"abc"` takes four hours to run, your program will wait 4 hours before calling `system("xyz")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether system executed correctly by looking what it has returned to you. If it executed successfully, the return value will be zero (null pointer).

From C++ Reference:

> If command is a null pointer, the function returns a non-zero value in case a command processor is available and a zero value if it is not.
>
> If command is not a null pointer, the value returned depends on the system and library implementations, but it is generally expected to be the status code returned by the called command, if supported.